# how to connect Apache flink to rabbitmq?

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq, apache-flink

I get an error when trying to connect Apache Flink to rabbitmq. I did this project with Apache Maven but the error still remains. in this project i use from mvn clean package for compile but i have a error.later i use  from idea compiler but i have error.

my code is :

```
package org.apache.flink;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.RMQSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.common.RMQConnectionConfig;
class App
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.enableCheckpointing(10);
    final RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
            .setHost("local")
            .setPort(5000)
            .build();
    final DataStream<String> stream = env
            .addSource(new RMQSource<String>(
                    connectionConfig,            
                    "queueName",                 
                    true,                        
                    new SimpleStringSchema()))   
            .setParallelism(1);             
}
}
```

my pom is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
<artifactId>flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.12</artifactId>
<version>1.8.1</version>

<name>flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.12</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
<pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven    defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
  <plugins>
    <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current  /maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see   https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </plugin Management>
   </build>
   </project>
```

When I run the program I encounter the following error

my error is :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and  try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache /flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at  sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that You have Your Flink dependencies in `provided` scope, because normally if You are running Your applications on Flink cluster, the Flink binaries are already there, so You don't need to include them in Your fat jar thus they are in scope `provided`. But I assume that You are running Your jobs locally and thus the Flink dependencies are not available for compilation, in such case You need to change the scope, so that the dependencies are available in compile-time. If You change the `scope` for Flink dependencies or remove it totally from `pom.xml` (the default scope is `compile`) it should work fine.

Comment: Please explain op why the scope is 'provided' and how is it related to job submission in flink.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your help changed my error and gave me a new one.
  Do you know what reference is needed to fix these errors?

Comment: I want a write simple connection between flink and rabbitmq but i have a many error. do you have a connection simple for flink?